# Passing data back into a previous activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

We have been learning how to open new Activities, in class, but so far the second activity runs its logic from the `OnCreate()` class.

I am wanting to return directly to activity one, from activity two, but run a function in its java when I do so.

All I've been able to find on the matter is how to effectively write my own "back" button.

I am needing to pass a string, as well as an int, that was originally sent from activity one to activity two. I need to compare the received int with the sent int to confirm it is coming from the same source.

My biggest problem is that we were taught to use `OnCreate()`. **This will not work on returning to an Activity, as OnCreate only runs when the instance is first created. If I am creating the instance as I move back, my other function will not work.**

Comment: use shared preferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an startActivityForResult method.

Here is a topic of that: [How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Goddamit. it actually says that in the notes. Only its worded like "create a function to run your logic, and call it this to keep it neat".